# REST and showing URIs that need user input

Tags: rest

I have a REST Service that works with Models.  So once a user has navigated to a model I allow two endpoints `/ModelRootItems` and also `/Item`.

The `/Item` endpoint requires an ID of an item within the model eg: `/Item/1234`.

When a user gets to a model I return the following URIs:

```
/Model/My_Model/ModelRootItems

/Model/My_Model/Item/{ItemID}
```

But I feel that I should not expose the `/Item` URI as it is not complete without an ID.  Users are able to see that the `/Item` endpoint exists via my help page.

So is it right/wrong to show this endpoint in the list of URIs?

Comment: try to explain bit more

Comment: Show it where? In the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are right/wrong choices in this case. However, I'd suggest you use

```
/Model/My_Model/Items
```

(notice the plural form `Items`) to return a list containing all the items of that `Model` and

```
/Model/My_Model/Items/{ItemID}
```

to return the single `Item` referenced by the ID.
Please note that this is just a convention, as I already said, there is no right/wrong choice in this case, especially if you use REST's `HATEOAS` principle with opaque URIs.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I suppose my concern is I'm showing a URI that is incomplete (if the user tried to use it, it would fail), so would that be bad?

Comment: If you expose a URI that has no associated endpoint (i.e. there is no service listening at that precise URI), then it is bad.

Comment: With regard to the Item and Items, the product the REST Service is running on already has defined interfaces and Item and Items are used to access a single item and items would be a group (eg: Item("1234") and Items("Classes").  So I'm tied in with existing terminology.

Comment: So my I currently have a /Item{ItemID} `WebGet` setup, but should I also have a /Item `WebGet` to catch when an ID has not been provided.  If so what should I show the user if they don't provide an ID?

Comment: I think you should return 400 (`Bad Request`).